# Why printing a int static value gives object notation value, instead of actual value

Tags: java

I am trying to print static int value in main method of java, when I am printing it is giving me value as `[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922` as object notation instead of actual value.  Could you please explain what is happening under internally.

Also, when I am trying using ClassName.varibaleName its working and printing correct value. Also, when I am printing using object. it is showing the correct result.

I am seeing the issue only when I am directly accessing the value of static variable in main method.

I also, tried creating other method and it is giving the result.

```
class Demo1 {

    static int a;

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Demo1 demo1 = new Demo1();
        demo1.inc();
        Demo1 demo2 = new Demo1();
        demo2.inc();
        Demo1 demo3 = new Demo1();
        demo3.inc();
        System.out.print("Count value is=" + a);
        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.print("\n" + demo1.a);
        System.out.print(demo2.a);
        System.out.print(demo3.a);
    }

    public static void inc() {
        a = a + 1;
        System.out.println("Value a" + a);
    }

}
```

I am getting below Result:

```
Value a1
Value a2
Value a3
Count value is=[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922
333
```

But expecting Count value is= `3` instead of `[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922`

Comment: `System.out.print("Count value is=" + a);` prints a `String[]`.

Comment: ^^ because `a` is the parameter to `main` where you receive command-line arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `int a` is not visible in a method that also has a local variable called `String[] a` (which will be used instead).

This is called "shadowing". The "closest" variable definition wins.

Use better variable names to avoid this.